# Greenbone Security Assistant 7.0.3 Host HTTP Header

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openvas

Recently I've set up an Amazon EC2 instance of Ubuntu 16.04 that was authorized to scan an IP block. The version of GSA that I have installed is 7.0.3. Currently, I can locally access GSA through the EC2 instance or remotely using my public Amazon elastic IP.

Additionally, I've allowed external access to GSA's listening port from my IP block. Currently, I can access GSA without any problems using my instances static public IP over HTTPS.

The problem that I'm currently running into is accessing GSA using a FQDN.

For example, I want to be able to use https://gsa.mydomain.com
My local DNS server has an A record with the FQDN and my EC2 instances public IP.

On my instance, I ran the following command.

```
sudo gsad --allow-header-host gsa.mydomain.com
```

However, browsing to https://gsa.mydomain.com produces the following error.

"The request contained an unknown or invalid Host header. If you are trying to access GSA via its hostname or a proxy, make sure GSA is set up to allow it."

Neither restarting GSA services or my instance had no effect.

Clearly, DNS is working but the host header command is not.

Any thoughts on how I can make this happen?

Additionally, for reference, I used the following URL

https://github.com/greenbone/gsa/pull/318

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ubuntu/debian edit /etc/default/openvas-gsa file and set ALLOW_HEADER_HOST=*HOSTNAME*
where *HOSTNAME* is your host name in the browser address line.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `Kali` and was able to figure this out my modifying the `systemd` service files. Modify the file `/lib/systemd/system/greenbone-security-assistant.service`, adding the `--allow-header-host gsa.mydomain.com` to the end of the ExecStart line.

For example, change the line from:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gsad --foreground --listen=<internal IP> --port=<configured web server port> --mlisten=<internal IP> --mport=<configured management port>
```

to:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/gsad --foreground --listen=<internal IP> --port=<configured web server port> --mlisten=<internal IP> --mport=<configured management port> --allow-header-host gsa.mydomain.com
```

Then run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart greenbone-security-assistant.service openvas-manager.service openvas-scanner.service
```